# Enable WebGL Browser HTML5 Applciation WP8?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, webgl

I am developing HTML5 games for mobile devices and am having problems with drawing without WebGL enabled.  When I enable WebGL my problems are fixed but on Windows Phone 8 is it possible to enable this as a developer using the HTML5 WP8 template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL is not supported by IE10 mobile (or desktop for that matter).

Comment: Is there any alternative? Anyway to build it into my application?

Comment: Windows Phone doesn't support any form of OpenGL, so I'm afraid you're out of luck

Comment: Okay that is what I was worried about. Looks like I will have to go a different route then I am right now then. May just code it natively.

Answer (score 1):

If you already installed the latest Windows Phone 8.1 update, the built-in IE11 now supports WebGL.

http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-features